# Passing error messages to another page

Tags: php, forms

What options are available to send an error message back to the form page?

I have a form on `login.php` it submits to `process.php`. `process.php` handles the db connection, validation etc. If there is an error, I want to pass that back to `index.php`.

ie:

```
    } else {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: /login");
    $error = "Sorry, that user name or password is incorrect. Please try again.";
}
```

Since these are two different files, what are the best options available to set and retrieve the errors? `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Session could be a good candidate, it does not clutter your URL. Just be sure to also remove it after it is read out.

Comment: Session is a terrible solution - why not to show the message in the script, that has been processing the data?

Comment: @zerkms That would depend heavily on his architecture. With the data given, and what was asked, session is the logical choice

Comment: @zerkms - Why is it a bad idea? What do you mean, "show the message in the script"?

Comment: @Paul: why do you need to redirect to `/login.php`? Why cannot you just `echo $error;` right in the current script?

Comment: @zerkms for usability and UI reasons. If I just echo the error message, I won't have much control over it. I want my logic seperate

Comment: @Paul: and the obvious and common solution is to process by the same script you output. "Separating logic" doesn't mean you need to have million files and perform million redirects between them. Having form and form processing logic in one (set) file is a good practice. And using sessions for error messages - isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific case, and with the code given, `$_SESSION` is your best bet. I.e:

```
$_SESSION['login_error_msg'] = "Sorry, that user name or password is incorrect. Please try again.";
```

Then back in index.php you'd have to check that session variable somehow, e.g:

```
if( ! empty($_SESSION['login_error_msg']))
{
    //display the message however you want
    unset($_SESSION['login_error_msg'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using $_SESSION. For one, you don't have to worry about refresh, and if you used $_GET, and scum of the universe can share a page and change the query string to mess with what shows up on your page.

If you have $_SESSION and if you create a unique identifier for each form you have, you can show a warning and then after the warning is output, unset that value in the $_SESSION array

e.g. to set it up

```
$_SESSION['uniq_form']['warning'] = 'You got this wrong';
```

next page:

```
echo $_SESSION['uniq_form']['warning'];
unset($_SESSION['uniq_form']['warning']);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to just use $_SESSION.

process.php:

```
<?php 
 else {
//session_destroy();

$_SESSION['error'] = "Sorry, that user name or password is incorrect. Please try again.";
header("Location: /login");
exit():
}
```

login.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
   echo $_SESSION['error'];
   unset( $_SESSION['error'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that $_SESSION would be your best bet without exposing too much information to your users.